# Chunk patch uploading to online GitHub then push online for low-speed networks

Tags: github

I am on a low-speed network. How can I push large git commits with some kind of resume capability? Like, can I upload chunks of patch files then combine them on the git server, then push them to master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I'd recommend git for such purposes, since it compresses everything and transmits quite efficiently.

Anywho -- you could have a branch from which you'd `cherry-pick` one commit at a time and push them individually, so to say.

Btw, smaller commits are the way to go! ;-)

Also, you could create patches, of course, and upload them somehow else (scp, ...) which then might be a resumable way, and apply them on your git server. But I doubt, this would be more efficient, then using actually git.